# Unable to focus on inputs inside angular-ui-bootstrap modals on touch devices

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am a newbie in angular-js programming.I was using one angular-ui-bootstrap's Modal component, but I am having a strange issue, whenever i click on an input (text-box/Text-area) inside the modal, if i am using it in desktop/laptop it is working fine, but if i use it in Touch devices(I have a Samsung Galaxy tab) and try to type something in it, then it doesn't get focus on touch... 
This bug reproduction requires:

1. Having an input inside of a UI Bootstrap modal box
2. Having angular-touch enabled (checked against 1.2 and 1.3)
3. Being on a touch device or using Chrome's touch emulation

Repro steps:

1. Click the button to open the modal, and then
2. click on the text input field.

On touch devices, the field will momentarily get focus and then lose it. With a normal mouse click, it's fine.

here is the plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/urvUIa/preview

Comment: It seems to work in the plnkr both on chrome's emulation and on my S6 Edge... ??

Comment: @ user1775718 well, that's kinda strange, I had it tested it was not working, the issue was there, but now somehow it appears to be fixed there.. will check again

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue on the angular-ui-bootstrap GitHub repo [Here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2017) with a suggested work around.

Comment: no. the solution doesnot work... i have tried to use the directive stopPropagation... but not useful :(

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue in my angular app:

I got an input box on click of which I need to trigger an event before user could start typing:

```
<input type="text" id="locationInput" ng-click="checkIfCartEmpty()" class="form-control"/>
```

After struggling for more then an hour and 10s of google search i din't find any solution.Probably it occurs due to some bug in ngTouch library thats what I found from a similar thread in git.

So after a series a hit and try I found that it is occuring because of "**ng-click**" in input box.

So catch the click event i simply wrote this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#locationInput").on("click",function(){
    $scope.checkIfCartEmpty();
  });
});
```

And it worked like a charm!

Comment: ,have you had the input inside a angular-ui-bootstrap modal pop-up?